# Has anyone tried using Aurelia with Document DB? Can you share what worked and what doesnt?

Tags: aurelia, azure-cosmosdb

I have used Document DB - run some queries using https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo. Now I would like to write an app and was thinking of using Aurelia. Anyone tried to use Aurelia with Document DB. Anything to watch out for?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend connecting Aurelia to DocumentDB through some middleware, e.g. a Node.js server.

You can find a pretty good blog post on this subject here:

- [Data Points - Aurelia Meets DocumentDB: A Matchmaker’s Journey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt620011.aspx) *by Julie Lerman*